# Convert carriage return string literal to carriage return

Tags: c#, string, encoding, mstest, carriage-return

I have a data driven test in C# that verifies a function properly creates a string given an input.

Code under test:

```
public static class Formatter
{
    public static String FormatWithCarriageReturn(int position)
    {
        return String.Format("#0 P{0} T1000 \r", position);
    }
}
```

The `FormatWithCarriageReturn` *must* return the string with the carriage return appended.

In order to test this method, I created a data driven test in MSTest that loads data from a CSV file.

CSV File:

```
position, expected
1, #0 P1 T1000 \r
2, #0 P2 T1000 \r
3, #0 P3 T1000 \r
4, #0 P4 T1000 \r
5, #0 P5 T1000 \r
6, #0 P6 T1000 \r
```

Test Method:

```
/* Test method and data source attributes*/
public void FormattingWithCarriageReturnFormatsCorrectly()
{
    String expected = TestContext.DataRow["expected"].ToString();
    /* various setup code. */
    int requestedPosition = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["position"]);
    String actual = Formatter.FormatWithCarriageReturn(requestedPosition);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

The problem is the `TestContext.DataRow["expected"].ToString()` statement will load the string literal `#0 P1 T1000 \\r`, and the `Assert` fails because it is comparing `#0 P1 T1000 \r` with `#0 P1 T1000`
<- I can't get this to format correctly.  There should be a carriage return at the end.

Is there a way to get the expected string out of the CSV file with the carriage return in place?  I could list the expected string in the CSV file as `#0 P1 T1000`, and then do something like `expected = String.Concat(expected, " \r");`, but I'd like to keep the full expected string in the CSV file.

Edit:  Here's the current Assert message that I'm getting:

```
Result1 Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<#0 P1 T1000 \r>. Actual:<#0 P1 T1000
>.
```

A passing message would read

```
Result1 Message: Assert.AreEqual passed. Expected:<#0 P1 T1000 
>. Actual:<#0 P1 T1000
>.
```

Note that both `expected` and `actual` have the carriage return at the end.

Comment: `return String.Format("#0 P{0} T1000 \r", position;` is that a typo.. you're missing an ending `)` also what if you use the `@` literal sign in  this 
`return String.Format(@"#0 P{0} T1000 \r", position);`

Comment: The test data does not contain a carriage return at all.  It ends with *two* characters, a backslash and an r.  Distinguish escape sequences in string literals from characters.  If you want a match then you need `expected = expected.Replace("\\r", "\r");

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "\r" from the lines in the csv file and change

```
String expected = TestContext.DataRow["expected"].ToString();
```

to

```
String expected = TestContext.DataRow["expected"].ToString() +
    new String(new[] { (char)0x0D });
```

Comment: Direct from the question:  "I could list the expected string in the CSV file as #0 P1 T1000, and then do something like expected = String.Concat(expected, " \r");, **but I'd like to keep the full expected string in the CSV file.**"

Comment: isn't carriage return 0x0D?

Comment: I was typing this during his final edits - I didn't see that he specified he wanted to keep the cr in the csv.